# node-xmpp-bosh error on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

I want to implement a bosh server. Because it is hard on Windows platform I decided to deploy it on an Ubuntu virtual machine via VMware. I made installation without problems. I took the process on this page: http://code.google.com/p/node-xmpp-bosh/wiki/DebianHowTo.
Now I want to test my bosh server with the command `sudo bosh` or `sudo /etc/init.d/bosh start` on the console I have `Starting bosh server.` After nothing.

I look the `bosh.err` file and I see `exec: 2: /usr/local/lib/bosh/run-server.js: Permission denied` I don̍ t know why this error with `sudo`.

---

I gave executable permission like  dhruvbird said: `chmod +x /usr/local/lib/bosh/run-server.js`.

Now when I execute the command `sudo bosh` I have `Starting bosh` on the terminal and `bosh.err` has this:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'ltx'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/bosh/src/bosh.js:26:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)̍
```

And when I execute the command `sudo /etc/init.d/bosh start` I always have `Starting bosh` on the terminal and this on the `bosh.err`:

`/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

And my bosh server doesn't work.

---

I run `dpkg -L nodejs | grep bin` or `dpkg -L node | grep bin` and I can read that the package is not install for each test. I run `apt-get update && apt-get install -u nodejs` and `apt-get update && apt-get install -u node` and always the same result. When I run `node -v` and have `v0.6.3` and I think this means that node is install. And I have the node directory on `home/node`. Is it a problem of path?

---

I  try to run `npm install node-xmpp-bosh` and this is the result on npm-debug.log:

```
...
info preuninstall node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6
info uninstall node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6
verbose unbuild node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6 [ true,
verbose unbuild node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6   '/home/frederic/node_modules',
verbose unbuild node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6   '/home/frederic/node_modules' ]
verbose binRoot [ '/home/frederic/node_modules/.bin',
verbose binRoot   { 'bosh-server': './run-server.js' } ]
info postuninstall node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6
ERR! Error: shasum check failed for /tmp/npm-1333573304110/1333573499309-0.1599154758732766/tmp.tgz
ERR! Expected: 1ceb545541dce5531c12187b80de902718a6afd2
ERR! Actual:   a3920de4ba03316b05b8c94163ea39ba3db434cc
ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/sha.js:25:20
ERR!     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/sha.js:49:5)
ERR!     at [object Object].emit (events.js:64:17)
ERR!     at afterRead (fs.js:1111:12)
ERR!     at Object.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:254:17)
ERR! You may report this log at:
ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
ERR! or email it to:
ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
ERR! 
ERR! System Linux 3.0.0-12-generic
ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "node-xmpp-bosh"
ERR! cwd /home/frederic
ERR! node -v v0.6.3
ERR! npm -v 1.1.15
ERR! message shasum check failed for /tmp/npm-1333573304110/1333573499309-0.1599154758732766/tmp.tgz
ERR! message Expected: 1ceb545541dce5531c12187b80de902718a6afd2
ERR! message Actual:   a3920de4ba03316b05b8c94163ea39ba3db434cc
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local/lib/bosh/run-server.js` show?

Comment: It shoes: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4889 2012-04-01 18:50 /usr/local/lib/bosh/run-server.js`

Comment: You probably need to give that script executable permissions: chmod +x /usr/local/lib/bosh/run-server.js

Comment: You probably also need to install the dependencies. First get npm from npmjs.org and the go to then try to install the bosh server by just saying: *$ npm install node-xmpp-bosh* This command should fetch all dependencies for you.

Comment: Your npm seems to be buggy - try updating it.

Comment: I udate my npm and I always have the same error `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory` on bosh.err file.

Comment: ah! that's because you don't have **node** in your path ($PATH). Try running **node** and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

This means `bosh` has been written to use an odd little idiom for shell scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

This runs the `env(1)` program, which will search its `PATH` for the `node` executable and execute it with a modified environment -- but, without environment modifications, it just runs `node`. It's a bit silly, but it is also the easiest way to write a script that doesn't hardcode the path to its interpreter.

You don't have a `node` program executable on your system. Perhaps `node` isn't yet installed. (I have a vague memory that old versions were actually named `nodejs` -- but I cannot find documentation to support this memory.)

To make sure `node` is installed, run:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -u nodejs
```

If the `nodejs` package is already installed, then perhaps the executable name is different. Run `dpkg -L nodejs | grep bin`, and look for the executable name in the output. If you don't see `/usr/bin/node`, I'll help walk you through setting up a symbolic link.

Comment: I run dpkg -L nodejs | grep bin or dpkg -L node | grep bin and I can read that the package is not install for each test. I run apt-get update && apt-get install -u nodejs and apt-get update && apt-get install -u node and always the same result.

Comment: hi how set up a symbolic link and firstly what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

To fix `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory` you can execute `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems on one of my servsers CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
I have fixed it using these commands:

```
# yum install nodejs
# yum install npm
# npm install ltx
# npm install underscore
# npm install node-lumberjack
# npm install node-uuid
# npm install eventpipe
# npm install node-expat
# npm install ejs
# npm install dns-srv
# npm install tav
# npm install ws
```